# Upgrading a PC with a dell top mounted PSU case

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, mount, computer-building

I'm building a PC, and I'd like to reuse my current case from a dell insperion, with an EVGA - 80 PLUS 600W ATX. From what I understand only the case dictates whether the PSU can be bottom or top mounted, and the PSU can be mounted in the case top or bottom.

In my case it must be top as there is no room in the bottom, and I'm additng additional hardware such as a  a gpu(RX 480 4gb powercolor red dragon) into my PC.

Since this will add more heat to the PC- Will my PSU get overheated from taking all that heat from within my case?

Comment: @Ramhound It is very clear that he is asking about the fact that his PSU is mounted at the top of the case, thus acting as a main exhaust. New schools of though avoid this  and put it on the bottom. He is worried how a high-end GPU's upward heat would affect the PSU.

Comment: Why are you all voting to close with the unclear what's being asked option, without first having a discussion with him about what he is asking? That seems anti-helpful to him and the site.

Comment: Eh, I'm disagreeing that the question is unclear- or that it belongs elsewhere. Its also a question I've actually wondered about.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You're right. I was trying to save it from closure limbo, by at least moving it to hardware building..

Comment: On the other hand, having the only answer here, I have a vested interest here, so I don't want to mod-dehammer this on my own ;p. I'm going to fix the question thougj.

Comment: @Louis I rarely talk about a vote I issue until after I issue it.  If something happens so I can reverse the vote I strive for that outcome.

Comment: @Ramhound I feel like there's a strong will on SE towards closure or other self-governing options as a primary option, which seems incorrect I also sense there's a general misunderstanding that's leading to power abuse at the expense of the user; user toolkit first, interact with user later. A reversal is still a show of power. Power holders are more readily using this abilities than the basic power to write a comment for the sake of help.

Comment: If issuing a vote without commentary is power abuse I will delete my account.  I left a comment, question was modified, I removed my cmoment and retracted my close vote.  The review process seems to have worked

Comment: It didn't I had to flag it under the pretext that the review process was failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's utterly no difference between a top and bottom mounted PSU. Its the exact same PSU, mounted upside down. You may want to check the *length* of the PSU and video cards you have, since enthusiast cases (and hardware) tend to be bigger/longer. Your PSU will always *intake* cold air and blow it into the case - as such the overall temperature of the PSU wouldn't be directly reliant on the heat output of the components, and forced airflow would overcome natural convection.

[image]

Here's a picture of the reference ATX layout off [the ATX reference guide](http://www.formfactors.org/developer%5Cspecs%5Catx2_2.PDF). For some reason its sideways, or everyone's been doing it wrong. Note the complete lack of case fans in this layout . Also note the blue lines showing how air flows through this layout, and that your PSU *sucks* cold air in, and blows tepid air across your PSU. .

Cases with bottom mounted power supplies don't cheap out and typically have additional dedicated fans blowing cold air from outside on the CPU, as opposed to slightly warmed air from the power supply across your CPU. The mounting holes are *identical* and there's no such thing as a special bottom mountable PSU

Having seen the horror that are dell PSUs you're likely trading up from a 90mm fan blowing less air noisily to a 120mm fan with more airflow. There's unlikely to be an issue there.

Comment: I suspect his concerns are with thermal management, and such, rather than actual physical sizes

Answer (score 1):

I will add that the PSU fan is there to dissipate primarily for the sake of the PSUs own ability to perform as rated. As its components rise in temperature, they eventually become less efficient (meaning their maximum power output drops).

If the sum of your parts approach the PSU wattage rating and you've added a high power drawing, heat wasting card to have your PSU deal with for heat exhaust and energy, then heat is something you should keep in mind.

If all is well, then fine. If you can link crashes to heavy GPU usage, and your parts need your PSU run near its rated ceiling, then heat could be the simple fix that you need to deal with.